# SQL select in from a field containing comma separated keys

Tags: sql

Is there a way I can construct a SQL statement that will help me retrieve active records based on status then references to oldids stored in another field?

Let's say I want to join the data below to another table. For ID=4, it is meant to imply that IDs 1,3 and 4 are combined and the surviving record is 4.

So when I want to join it with another table, how can I have scvid 104 be linked to transactions of IDs 1,3, and 4?

```
select * 
from tbl 
where scvid in (id, oldids)?
```

Sample data:

```
scvid    id    oldid    status
------------------------------
101      1     NULL        0
102      2     NULL        1
103      3     NULL        0
104      4     [1,3]       1
```

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: What DB you use (MSSQL, MySql, ....)?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your DB system. Here is the solution for SQL Server (TSQL). You can use it also in another RDBMS with minor changes

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, t2.scvid as NEWID 
FROM 
    tbl t1
JOIN 
    tbl t2 ON
    -- first case: if the record is main with [1,3] we link it to the the self 
    (t1.scvid = t2.scvid) AND (t2.oldid IS NOT NULL)
    OR 
    -- second case: we bulid ",1,3," from "[1,3]" 
    -- then we get condition ",1,3," LIKE "%,id,%" 
    -- for the id = 1 and 3 it's TRUE
    (REPLACE(REPLACE(t2.oldid,'[',','),']',',') 
        LIKE '%,'+CAST(t1.id as VARCHAR(100))+',%') 
    AND (t1.oldid IS NULL)
```

RESULT:

```
scvid   id  oldid   status  NEWID
101 1   NULL    0           104
103 3   NULL    0           104
104 4   [1,3]   1           104
```

This output new column `NEWID` for the old `Id` in this record so you can JOIN or use it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres you can do this by converting the comma separated list into an array.

Something like this:

Sample setup:

```
create table some_table (id integer);
insert into some_table values (4), (6), (8);

create table service (svcid integer, id integer, oldid text, status integer);
insert into service
values
(101, 1, NULL , 0),
(102, 2, NULL , 1),
(103, 3, NULL , 0),
(104, 4, '1,3', 1);
```

To get all rows from `some_table` where the `id` is either the `id` column of the `service` table or any of those in the `oldid` column you can use:

```
select *
from some_table st
  join (
    select svcid, id, oldid, status, string_to_array(s.oldid, ',')::int[]||id as all_ids
    from service s
  ) s on st.id = any(s.all_ids)
```

This returns:

```
id | svcid | id | oldid | status | all_ids
---+-------+----+-------+--------+--------
 4 |   104 |  4 | 1,3   |      1 | {1,3,4}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on SQL Server.
Since that LIKE syntax supports a negative character class as `[^0-9]`.

```sql
select 
old.scvid as old_scvid, old.id as old_id, 
new.scvid as new_scvid, new.id as new_id, new.oldid as new_oldids
from tbl new
left join tbl old 
  on (old.status = 0 and new.oldid like concat('%[^0-9]',old.id,'[^0-9]%'))
  where new.status = 1 
  and new.oldid is not null
```

To bad that the table doesn't have a "newid" field, instead of that "oldid" with a range.
That would make it a lot easier to join.

Comment: In (standard) SQL `LIKE` only supports `_` and `%` as wildcards. "patterns" or similar "regular expressions" are not supported by `LIKE`.